# How to print R evaluation in RDotNet

Tags: c#, r, linear-regression, lm, r.net

I test a simple code in R-Gui but I don't know how print same result in RdotNet via c#.

```
library(ISLR)
data(Auto)
attach(Auto)
reg<- lm(mpg~horsepower)
summary(reg)
```

The result is :
Call:
    lm(formula = mpg ~ horsepower)

```
Residuals:
   Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-13.5710  -3.2592  -0.3435   2.7630  16.9240 

Coefficients:
           Estimate Std.  Error   t value   Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) 39.935861   0.717499   55.66   <2e-16 ***
horsepower  -0.157845   0.006446  -24.49   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 4.906 on 390 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.6059,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.6049 
F-statistic: 599.7 on 1 and 390 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

But, how i can print some information with RDotNet in this code:

```
engine.Evaluate("reg <- lm(df$weight ~ df$lenght)").AsNumeric();
var r = engine.Evaluate((summary(reg));  
Console.WriteLine(r);
```

This cause an error. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Hello and Welcome to stackoverflow, What error does this cause?

Comment: `Error: (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'
Fatal error: unable to initialize the JIT`